# Perl, Moose - subclass is not inheriting methods of a superclass

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance, moose

I'm new to Perl and have been directed to Moose as the go to source for Perl OO but I am having some problems with making it work. Specifically, methods of the superclass do not seem to be inherited.
To test this I have created three files which contain the following:

thingtest.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
require "thing_inherited.pm";
thing_inherited->hello();
```

thing.pm

```
package thing;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;

sub hello
{
    print "poo";
}

sub bye
{
    print "naaaa";
}

1;
```

And finally, thing_inherited.pm

```
package thing_inherited;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;

extends "thing";

sub hello
{
    bye();
}

1;
```

So what one would normally expect is for method bye to be inherited as part of the subclass but I am given this error instead...

```
Undefined subroutine &thing_inherited::bye called at thing_inherited.pm line 11.
```

Can anyone explain if I'm doing something wrong here? Thanks!

edit: In doing this I have come across another conundrum: calling a method in my base class from my superclass that has should have been overwritten by the superclass is not overwritten.
Say I had

```
sub whatever
{

    print "ignored";

}
```

in my base class and added

```
whatever();
```

in my bye method, calling bye would not produce the overwritten result, only print "ignored".

Answer (score 8):

You have a function call, not a method call. Inheritance only applies to classes and objects, i.e. method calls. A method call looks like `$object->method` or `$class->method`.

```
sub hello
{
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->bye();
}
```

---

By the way, `require "thing_inherited.pm";` should be `use thing_inherited;`

Comment: (While visiting one of SO's sister sites, I got the notification I got the "moose badge". Without context, I thought "What, for being Canadian???")

Answer (score 0):

Just a few fixes.  thing.pm was fine, but see the changes to thingtest.pl and thing_inherited.pm.

thingtest.pl: need to instantiate the object before using it, then you can use the method

```
use thing_inherited;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $thing = thing_inherited->new();
$thing->hello();
```

thing_inherited.pm: since the hello method is calling a method in it's class, you need to tell it just that

```
package thing_inherited;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;

extends "thing";

sub hello {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->bye();
  }

1;
```

Output:

> $ perl thingtest.pl
>
> naaaa$